# How to use typewriter plugin for show many <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I have some div tage with a same class like this :

```
div class="test"
```

I am using jquerytypewriter for effect text to show.
My problem is how i can  when a div end its hide and after div is start with jquerytypewriter effect

my body code is :

```
<div class="test">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
<div class="test">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
 <div class="test">ccccccccccccccccccccccc</div>
 <div class="test">dddddddddddddddddddddddd</div>
```

and my js code is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

m();
function m(){
    //alert($('.test').length);
    for(var i=0; i<$('.test').length ; i++){
$('.test').eq(i).typewrite({delay:20, extra_char : "_" , trim : true,callback : function(){
    $('.test').eq(i).hide(800);
    $('.test').eq(i).next().show(1000);

    }});

}
});
```

how can i Apply this effect One by one on divs .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var i = 0;
var x = $('.test').length;
m();
function m(){
    //alert($('.test').length);

    //for(var i=0; i<$('.test').length ; i++){  

    if(x>0)
$('.test').eq(i).typewrite({delay:20, extra_char : "" , trim : true,callback :setTimeout(function(){
    $('.test').eq(i).hide(1);
    i++;
    if(i==$('.test').length){i=0}
    m();
    },3000)});



    //}
}

});
```